# Puppet manifest: Overriding default variables in Hash

Tags: puppet, manifest

I've been handed the code for a Puppet module which was written by someone else. I've been tasked with getting it working in an actual Puppet environment.

I'm struggling to override defaults in the module in the `manifest` file. Hopefully this is a syntax issue, and not a issue with the init class.

In `init.pp`:

```
class our_module(
  # Defaults to be overridden in the manifest file 
  Hash $config = {
    'id' => '38e18a',
    'secret' => 'donttellanyone',
    'path' => '/test/path'
  }
){
# Logic here...
}
```

How can I override these attributes? I've tried the following which gives my an `InvalidCredentialsException`:

```
node 'my_node' {
  class { 'our_module':
    config => {
      id => 'newid',
      secret => 'newsecret',
      path => '/newpath
  }
}
```

I'm new to Puppet and still getting my head around the docs and the syntax.

Comment: The node definition is missing a closing quote after `'/newpath`, and a closing brace for the hash value, too.  But is that a faithful representation of the code you are actually using?  I would expect Puppet to reject it with a syntax error during catalog building, but that's not happening. It appears that instead, either Puppet's puppetserver component is failing before catalog building even begins, or your class is failing while being applied on the client side, after a catalog is successfully built.

Comment: Or if it does occur during catalog building, then I am inclined to think that the exception is related to something in your manifest set that you have omitted from the question.

Comment: The missing quote was just my error in adding the example code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Given class `our_module` as presented in the question, this variation on the node block is valid for declaring that class and customizing its `config` parameter:

```
node 'my_node' {
  class { 'our_module':
    config => {
      id => 'newid',
      secret => 'newsecret',
      path => '/newpath'
    }
  }
}
```

> Hopefully this is a syntax issue, and not a issue with the init class.

If what you're really using takes the same form as above, then I'm sorry to have to tell you that the problem is not with your class declaration.  If your Puppet runs are successful for nodes that do not declare class `our_module`, then my conclusion would be that the issue is indeed with the class implementation.

> I've tried the following which gives my an `InvalidCredentialsException`

I am disinclined to think that that arises during catalog building.  I cannot completely rule out the possibility, but that sure looks like a Java exception, whereas the catalog builder is implemented mainly in Ruby.  It could be coming from `puppetserver`, Puppet's Java-based server front end, but that would not depend on whether your manifests declare a particular class.  My crystal ball suggests that the `our_module` implementation is `Exec`ing a Java program when it is applied to the client, and that it is that program that is throwing the exception.

Some of those possibilities could be related to bad class parameter data, but I don't see any reason to think that the issue arises from a syntax error.

Comment: Thank for your response. The module is consuming a ruby SDK which makes some HTTP / Oauth2 calls. So no Java.

I neglected to include the full Error, so I will now. 
`Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, InvalidCredentialsException (file: <path to module init.pp> on node <puppet-client.home>`

When run with defaults (i.e. just `class { 'my_module' : }`)  the module works fine. It's only when I try to override the config variables it throws errors.